# docker.sock forwarding through ssh tunnel returns "page not found"

Tags: docker, ssh, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to access the contents of remote docker containers on a linux server from my windows machine by forwarding the remote docker socket over SSH. However, the localhost port I am forwarding it to just gives me {"message":"page not found"}, and the remote docker containers are not detected.

Ideally, I want to access the contents of the remote containers in VSCode. I've been following their walkthrough (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced#_option-2-connect-using-an-ssh-tunnel) on how to connect to a remote docker container. Per their walkthrough, I've also made sure to set "AllowStreamLocalForwarding yes" on the server's sshd_config

```
C:\Users\me> ssh -nNT -L localhost:23750:/var/run/docker.sock user@remote_server
```

goto http://localhost:23750/:

```
{"message":"page not found"}
```

Following the VSCode instructions:

In settings,

```
"docker.host":"tcp://localhost:23750"
```

however, clicking "Remote-Containers: Attach to a Running Container" only lists my local containers, to the server ones

I've not gotten any error messages from following these steps; however, I still don't have any access to the remote docker containers

Answer (score 0):

Solved - I was entering the docker.host setting wrong on vscode

(I had entered 
`"docker.host":""tcp://localhost:23750""`
instead of 
`"docker.host":"tcp://localhost:23750"`
)

Sorry for spam